# To override CSS of parent theme

Tags: css

First of all, I know very well that how to override css of parent theme. But on one property I got lots of trouble. I have a sitemap page in my project that contains `<UL> lists`. There are many `<ul>` have been used inside another `<ul>`(list inside list).
            Problem is that when a list(`<ul>`) starts with in another list(`<li>`) then list should start with some tab space but it won't. Because parent theme have defined properties shows below.

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend 
{
background: transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;
border: 0 none;
font-size: 100%;
margin: 0;
outline: 0 none;
padding: 0;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

In the above properties of parent theme I can solve my problem if i remove `padding: 0;` or set `padding: none` or `padding: -1`.
I typed this properties in my child theme css by setting `padding: none` or `padding: -1` even with `!important`. All other properties can be override easily but only that can't. Anyone knows why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Neither `padding: none;` nor `padding: -1;` are valid CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding), and are therefore ignored. Removing `padding: 0;` from the parent theme is inadvisable as it's "resetting" the (largely varied) default browser-applied style of many elements, and will likely create issues with other CSS on your site that expect such a reset.

You should specifically target the items you wish to change. So to add some space to the left of nested `<li>` elements, use new rules to add space to those elements rather than trying to remove the styles applied by the parent style-sheet.

```
ul>li li {
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```

Altering parent theme stylesheets is generally a bad idea if you are not the parent theme's author.

You may want to check out [this introduction to CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started) to get a better grasp on CSS selectors and inheritance.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, It solved my problem partially Not completely. It does add space in nested list But problem that i have now after applying your suggestion is that In nested list it shows a gap of 30px between bullet and the heading(list-name).

Comment: Then use the `margin` property instead of `padding`. Read up on [the CSS Box Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model) to understand why.

Comment: Hey thanks, Using `margin-left: 30px;` instead of `padding-left: 30px;` solved my problem.